# How to create a dynamic subdomains in t3 stack

Tags: next.js, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, trpc, t3-app

Anyone know a way to create dynamic subdomains in t3-stack?

I want to be able to build a subdomain system like **Hashnode** had in the past.

For Example:

```
test.hashnode.com
example.hashnode.com
abc.hashnode.com
```

I am using trpc, t3stack and nextjs for the project.

There are no videos, blog posts, documentation related to this.